# What does exactly does さま mean in dictionary definitions?

Tags: translation, dictionary

I've been using Japanese-Japanese dictionaries for a while now and this keeps popping up. It seems to me like a kind of usage that is found for the most part only in dictionaries. Can anyone help explain what exactly さま means in the dictionary definition below? (It's from [大辞泉](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0na&p=%E3%81%95%E3%81%95%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B).)  It seems to be just a generic object that they modify with the term's definition, i.e. XYZ is a blah blah blah さま (thing).

> ささ‐やか【細やか】
>
> ［形動］［文］［ナリ］１ 形や規模があまり大げさでなく、控えめな**さま**。「―な商売をはじめる」「―に暮らす」

Any clarification would be really appreciated.

Comment: (1) It is better to state the source when you quote something.  (2) Have you checked [さま](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE) in a dictionary?

Answer (score 10):

The `さま` in these definitions is none other than `様`.  `様` in this sense is synonymous with `有【あり】様` or `様子`, meaning "state, circumstances, situation, appearance, condition".

So the definition of `細やか` you provided would translate as "shape/scope not being grandiose or exaggerated, but being (a) reserved/moderate/conservative (state)".