# Meaning of ようす in definitions

Tags: meaning

I'm unsure about the meaning of ようす in some dictionary definitions. Most of the time I translate it in my mind to "State of being + adjective" but sometimes it doesn't seem to fit, like in the definitions I have for these two kanji:

> 峨 : 山の高くけわしい**ようす**。
>
> 嵯 : 山が高くけわしい**ようす**。

So, is it along the lines of "The fact, for a mountain, of being tall and steep" or rather "Looking high and steep like a mountain"?

Comment: Related:  [What does exactly does さま mean in dictionary definitions?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9915/78)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「[様子]{ようす}」 surely means "state", "situation", "circumstances", etc., but whether or not one of those English words should actually be used in the English translation of a definition of a Japanese word (or a single kanji as in this case) is a ***separate matter altogether*** IMHO.

Unlike in other languages including English, it is just customary in Japanese culture to end a definition with a noun such as 「様子」、「こと」 and 「さま」.  This occurs in definitions for words of multiple parts of speech including nouns, adjectives, adverbs etc. and sometimes even verbs.

In other words, **Japanese-speakers simply "expect" a word (or kanji) definition to come in the noun phrase form** because that is how we traditionally define words for one another both in  spoken and written Japanese.  That is how it is done whether it is a mother explaining a word to a toddler or a big dictionary or professor giving a word definiton to a Ph.D. student.

So, the important question is: "Is the same thing as above practiced by English-speakers?"

***If yes (or a strict literal translation is required for some reason)***, go ahead and give a definition in the noun phrase form starting with a word like "state".

***If no***, forget 「ようす」 and form the definition the way it will sound most natural to English-speakers, which I presume would be like:

"craggy and steep (as of a mountain)"

Finally, the translation "***looking*** high and steep ~~" sounds strange to me.  That is not really what 「ようす」 means in a word definition.

Comment: Thanks that was extremely useful, as always. I think you're right with the problem for me being that it's a noun phrase. Would the definition have the same meaning if phrased 「高く険しい山の様子」? If yes, would it be ok for it to appear in a dictionary like this or would it sound clumsy?