# Explaining the sentence 今になってもまだ実現していないさま

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have two questions regarding this sentence:

> 今になってもまだ実現していないさま。

1. The meaning /  grammar of ~も in 今になっても.
2. The meaning / grammar of ~さま part at the end of the sentence. As I know ~さま is added to the names at the end when you addressing to someone in official language.

I found this sentence at goo [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/14919/meaning/m0u/) explaining the 未だ.

Comment: Maybe you could give the context of this sentence (i.e. where you found it).

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9915/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「今{いま}になってもまだ実現{じつげん}していない**さま**」

First, this is not a sentence; It is only a noun phrase (a relative clause).  Everything that is in front of 「さま」 modifies 「さま」.  It is 「様」 in kanji.

> 1) The meaning / grammar of ~も in 今になっても.

Here, 「も」 means "even". 「今になっても」 means "even now", "even at this point", etc.

> 2) The meaning / grammar of ~さま part at the end of the sentence. As I know ~さま is added to the names at the end when you addressing to someone in official language.

This 「さま」 has nothing to do with the honorific 「様{さま}」 as in 「田中和夫{たなかかずお}**様**」 and that should be clear from the context this time.

「さま」 here means the "state", "situation", etc.  More specifically, it refers to "**the way something/someone is or someone does something (and how it looks)**".

Thus, the phrase means:

> "the state/situation where something has not become a reality even now (as of now)"